# Locating links within excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I've tried each of the suggestions.  I was able to find some of the items under Name Manager and removed those links.  However, I still have a link to another excel file that is being prompted each time I open to update.  I did a search and cannot locate the file this way. I tried renaming my file as a .zip file and can see the path of the external link as suggested, but again, cannot find it within the file. What am I missing.

Comment: Which suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Typical places where links can be hiding include

- formulas
- named ranges
- data validation
- charts (series formulas, etc)
- data sources (think pivot tables)
- VBA

It can be hard to find them all when combing through a workbook manually. Long-time Excel MVP Bill Manville has written a free add-in that you can download at the link below. It has found all links that I ever needed finding.

http://www.manville.org.uk/software/findlink.htm